# How to set a turtle variable in a range of values randomly?

Tags: netlogo

I need to set a turtle variable in a range of values randomly, the range must go from 800 to 1000.

I wrote this code:

```
turtles-own [income]

to setup
 create-turtles 100 [
     set income range 800 1000
     ]
end
```

The code is not working.

I tried ramdom-float but the values range from 0 to max value.

Answer (score 4):

range returns a list of numbers between the start and stop, where you want to choose a number from a range---these are different.

I didn't find a random-range or a random-uniform, so these are some approaches:

You can do a random number between 0 -200 and just add 800 to scale to your range.

```
turtles-own [income]
to setup
 create-turtles 100 [
     set income (random 200) + 800
     ]
end
```

Alternatively, if you want to create a list using the range function and choosing one of them.

```
turtles-own [income]

to setup
 create-turtles 100 [
     set income one-of (range 800 1000)
     ]
end
```

Comment: although `one-of range 800 1000` will certainly work, it will run _much much_ slower than `random 200 + 800`